# Responsive text -- Function not Initializing with FitText and FlexSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive slider using FlexSlider.
I also want the text under each slider to resize. FitText does not initialize on any slide except for the first, or if I resize the window.
How can I make this work (with no FOUC)?
Should work in IE 8 up, plus modern browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/adtVP/11/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <figure>
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/" alt="" />
              <figcaption>
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
                <p>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco </p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" />
              <figcaption>
                <h1>uis nostrud exercitation ullamco </h1>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco </p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people/" alt="" />
              <figcaption>
                <h1>ncididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h1>
                <p>abore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco </p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>​
```

**CSS**

```
    .flex-control-nav, .flex-control-paging {
        clear: both;
    }

    .flexslider {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .flexslider img {
      min-width: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 23px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .slides li {display: none}
```

**JS**

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider();

$(".slides h1, .slides p").fitText();  ​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this would be helpful http://jsfiddle.net/adtVP/40/

roadmap:

1. read on short note on css tricks about [`fitText`](http://css-tricks.com/fittext/) plugin
2. took Paul Irish's cross browser implementation for fixing `resize` event in different browsers
3. switched from `px` to `em` (or any other relative values like %) on font sizes only here:

   ```
   ...
   h1 {
       font-size: .5em;
       width: 100%;
   }
   p {
      font-size: .2em;
      width: 100%;
   }
   ...
   ```

   made bit modification to the way how fit text are called

   ```
   $(".slides").fitText();
   ```

this basically will update font size on a parent level element which will make effect for `em` based font of children, and this is the whole idea.

also call the fit Text every time when window resized using snippet code from Paul.

that's it, code it rough and needs to be cleaned and glanced but works.

UPD: code from the github source for fitText is blocked in IE by mismatching mime type, and that caused problems.
As a alternative solution you may just include source in your js file with correct type, and that will work.

old **IE not working** example is here http://jsfiddle.net/adtVP/35/ leave it here for the record, the new one above tested with IE Debug Toolbar down to 7 version, for sure it is not the same as a real browsers but so far so good.

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't work in IE. I really would need it work work in IE 8-9, and degrade in IE7. IE8 doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/master/jquery.fittext.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch 
2
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'fitText'

Comment: that's the problem with IE, it blocks fitText from github

Comment: Kudos for the `em` unit implementation and the `.slides` target from jQuery. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
before: function(slider) {
    $(".slides h1, .slides p").css("color","#ffffff"); 

  },

after: function(slider) {
    $(".slides h1, .slides p").css("color","#000000"); 
    $(".slides h1, .slides p").fitText(); 

  }
});

 $(".slides h1, .slides p").fitText();
```

Comment: No, because there is a flash of un-styled content. http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/Duam2/2/

Comment: well what changes I made worked in jsfiddle.Actually the slides hide property hides all p's and h1's and hence fitText is not able to add changes to it.

Comment: lets try this - put the entire code except -  $(".slides h1, .slides p").fitText(); in a function and call the function just before the </body>

Comment: ok, i dont know whether it would be acceptable to you ... but try this trick - let the color of the text initially be white (or background color) and on fittext, change the font color to black.

Comment: Please make a fiddle of your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I have made the modification on jsfiddle, re edited the answer too. Now I make sure that the color is white, so it is not visible when fittext is called.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS for Flexslider hides all the `li` elements which are then shown by `flexslider()`, so the text the `fitText()` is targeting can't be evaluated, unless it is in the first, initially visible slide. I tried working around this by running this before Flexslider:

```
var slider = $('.flexslider'),
    hiddenSlides = slider.find('.slides > li:not(".slides > li.flex-active-slide")'),
    text = hiddenSlide.find('.text');

hiddenSlide.show();

text.fitText();

hiddenSlide.hide();
```

This solved the issue on `load`. I also tried wrapping this in a function and calling it on the `resize` event, however this didn't work for me. If anyone can fill in the blanks, that would be great.